# not getting indicator image on TabPageIndicator

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs, android-tablelayout

Am using `ViewPager` and `TabPageIndicator` for showing multiple tabs.
I have applied all the styles also added `android:theme="@style/StyledIndicators` 
in manifest. But still not getting desier output.

What am expecting is

[image]

but my current output is

[image]

Am i missing any thing? I have added all required images in drawebales.

And here is my `style.xml`

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="PoppupMenu" parent="android:Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
 </style>

<style name="Widget"></style>

<style name="TextAppearance.TabPageIndicator" parent="Widget">
   <!--  <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item> -->
    <!-- <item name="android:textColor">@color/vpi__dark_theme</item> -->
</style>

<style name="StyledIndicators" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomTabPageIndicator</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.TabPageIndicator" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.TabPageIndicator</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/custom_tab_indicator_divider</item>
    <item name="android:showDividers">middle</item>
    <item name="android:dividerPadding">5dp</item>
     <item name="android:height">40dp</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTabPageIndicator" parent="Widget.TabPageIndicator">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_tab_indicator</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#218801</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/custom_tab_indicator_divider</item>
    <item name="android:showDividers">middle</item>
    <item name="android:fadingEdge">horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:fadingEdgeLength">8dp</item>
</style>
```

and `custom_tab_indicator.xml` is

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_tab_indicator_unselected" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_tab_indicator_selected" />

<!-- Focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_tab_indicator_unselected_focused" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_tab_indicator_focused" />

<!-- Pressed -->
<!--    Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_tab_indicator_unselected_pressed" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_tab_indicator_selected_pressed" />

<!--    Focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_tab_indicator_unselected_pressed" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_tab_indicator_selected_pressed" />
```

Comment: you put the backgroud Image on the button itself

Comment: yes ,that custom_tab_indicator? But it contains Images which are shown on First image. see my edit above.

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain you are right actually there was different image having same name inside draweble-mdpi  . solved my problem thanx :)